# I want to make my LITE edition, what steps I must do?

Tags: ios5

I have my app to the appStore (paid). I want to make a LITE edition of my app. 
BUT  I don't know what to do. I read some topics here in the forum but I am still confused!
What step I must follow???
Any help....

Comment: check this link out: [Creating different versions for apps](http://just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

you can just disable some features in full version, and make a link to promote your full version app inside your LITE version app.

What else? I see no problem at all.

Comment: Do I have to change in the .plist file the Bundle Identifier name? Do I have to create new App Id?